# limited Fibonacci series using python

Tags: python

I want to write a code that prints a list of Fibonacci series up to a specific number. In that case lets say its 30.
the problem is it always prints 1 number too many, it will print up to 34 instead of 21

```
l=[1,1]
i=0
while l[i+1]<30:
    l.append(l[i]+l[i+1])
    i+=1
print l
```

Comment: But when `l[i]` is 13, `l[i+1]` will be 21 which _is_ less than 30. Perhaps you want to check the result of `l[i]+l[i+1]` before you append to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to calculate the next term to see if it is bigger that 30 or not..

So you can choose to calculate it but not store it (clean solution):

```
l=[1, 1]
i = 0
while True:
    next_term = l[i]+l[i+1]
    if next_term > 30:        
        break
    else:
        l.append(next_term)
        i += 1
print l
```

or, using your existing script, simply not print it (dirty-ish solution):

```
l=[1,1]
i=0
while l[i+1]<30:
    l.append(l[i]+l[i+1])
    i+=1
print l[:-1]  # or l.pop(); print l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[1,1]
i=0
while l[i+1]<30:
    l.append(l[i]+l[i+1])
    i+=1
l.pop()
print l
```

You are appending after the check. Just pop it out in the end.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your `while` condition :

```
while (l[i]+l[i+1])<30:
```

s.t. :

```
l=[1,1]
i=0
while (l[i]+l[i+1])<30:
    l.append(l[i]+l[i+1])
    i+=1

>>> print(l)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```